# Springboot Could not resolve placeholder to hashmap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a springboot configuration yaml file with the follwing keys :

```
grpc:
  channels:
    service1:
      hostname: localhost
      port: 50015
    service2:
      hostname: localhost
      port: 50016
```

I want to load those keys to a hashmap  :

```
@Configuration
public class ChannelProperties {

    @Value("${grpc.channels}")
    private Map<String, ChannelConfiguration> channels;

    public ChannelProperties() {
    }

    public static class ChannelConfiguration {

        private String hostname;
        private String port;

    }
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'grpc.channels' in value "${grpc.channels}"
```

I still not able to find what i foget in my configuration any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) rather than the `@Value` annotation. Additionally, you need to add getters and setters for your properties.

Something like this should work:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "grpc")
public class ChannelConfig {

    private Map<String, ChannelConfiguration> channels;

    public Map<String, ChannelConfiguration> getChannels() {
        return this.channels;
    }

    public void setChannels(Map<String, ChannelConfiguration> channels) {
        this.channels = channels;
    }

    public static class ChannelConfiguration {
        private String hostname;
        private String port;

        public String getHostname() {
            return hostname;
        }

        public void setHostname(String hostname) {
            this.hostname = hostname;
        }

        public String getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(String port) {
            this.port = port;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the `@ConfigurationProperties`, it works fine

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "grpc")
public class ChannelProperties {

    private Map<String, ChannelConfiguration> channels;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class ChannelConfiguration {
        private String hostname;
        private String port;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the below configuration on main class.

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:foo.yml", factory = 
YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```